# onPreExexute method is not called

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-runonuithread

I'm trying to display a `Toast` when I call the `AsyncTask` class with `new saveWithStickers(BaseActivity.this).execute();` to notify the user that the save process being started, when I run the code below the `onPreExecute()` method for some logical reason is not called so the Toast does not appear as well,is `runOnUiThread` the reason for this behavior?

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public class saveWithStickers extends AsyncTask<Void, File, File> {
    File fileSaved;
    Context mContext;

    saveWithStickers(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        fileSaved = FileUtil.getNewFile(BaseActivity.this, "VAPOGRAM");
        if (fileSaved != null)
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                stickerView.save(fileSaved, true);
            });
        return fileSaved;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "saving ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
        super.onPostExecute(file);
}


saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckPermissionUtil checkPermissionUtil = new CheckPermissionUtil(BaseActivity.this);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkPermissionUtil.checkPermission(1812)) {
                        new saveWithStickers(BaseActivity.this).execute();
                    } else
                        checkPermissionUtil.requestPermission(1812);
                } else {
                    new saveWithStickers(BaseActivity.this).execute();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you calling the Async class and mention the class type such as activity or service or like so.

Comment: @HariNJha thank you for your comment can you see the post again

Comment: is it in a fragment: try getContext() in Toast.makeTet(getContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        public class saveWithStickers extends AsyncTask<Void, File, File> {
            File fileSaved;
            Context mContext;

            saveWithStickers(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected File doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                fileSaved = FileUtil.getNewFile(BaseActivity.this, "PHOTO EDITOR");
                if (fileSaved != null)
                    runOnUiThread(() -> stickerView.save(fileSaved, true));
                return fileSaved;
            }

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saving ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
                super.onPostExecute(file);

        }
    }
```

To access to the context you need to pass it or use [WeakRerefence](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference) to your parent activity

Comment: thank you so much for your answer when I call the **saveWithStickers** using `new saveWithStickers(getApplicationContext()).execute();` nothing happened the same issue still present, I can't see the Toast (Saving ....)

Comment: Try to print something to make sure it is really not called?

Comment: Yes using `Log` I'm able to see that `onPreExecute` have been called, But `Toast` no

Comment: Some stupid suggestions but I hope it may help you. Call Toast inside `runOnUiThread()` method. Second call toast method before  `super.onPreExecute();` Third remove  `@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")` annotation

Comment: And try  `saveWithStickers(this).execute();` not applicationContext

Comment: unfortunately, the same, the toast not appear

Comment: @pic where do you call `new saveWithStickers(getApplicationContext()).execute()`

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO.I have tried `new saveWithStickers(BaseActivity.this).execute()` and `new saveWithStickers(this).execute()` and new `saveWithStickers(getApplicationContext()).execute()`

Comment: @pic where do you do the testing? How about change with another phone/simulator? And please try `Toast.makeText(..)` from the `onResume` to see if it works